# Can't compile rsa.h on windows xp

Tags: c++, windows, openssl, rsa, codeblocks

I have faced with openssl surprises. I have installed openssl libs on my windows XP and tried to compile simple example on C++:

```
#include <openssl\rsa.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    RSA* rsa;
    unsigned char* input_string;
    unsigned char* encrypt_string;
    unsigned char* decrypt_string;

    if ( RSA_generate_key_ex( rsa, 1024, NULL, NULL) ) {
        printf( " I'm using RSA lib!\n" ) ;
    } ;

    return 0;
}
```

Also i configured path to "include" folder, but...

```
C:\Programming\C++_Projects\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `RSA_generate_key_ex'|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I'm using Codeblocks and google couldn't help me. I'm sad so much. Could you help me?)

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't link to a library you need to link to. It compiled fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler to link with the openssl library.

In CodeBlocks, you certainly have a tab Libraries (or something equivalent) in your project settings where you can add the openssl library.

Comment: I added libs for MinGW to linker settings and now it works! Big thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to set the answer as accepted if the answer solved your problem.